# To find the maximum number of distinct integers in a grid for given conditions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, permutations, combinations, discrete-optimization, packing-problem

**Problem:**

Consider a $n × n$ square grid made up of $n^2$ small boxes. Each Column and row
of this grid can contain upto a maximum of $m$ ($m <n$) ***distinct*** integers only. What is the **maximum** number of **distinct** integers that can be fitted in this grid so that no boxes remain empty?

**What I have already tried:**

I thought to start by putting distinct integers in the main diagonal. By this, we have filled $n$ boxes

Now, I put ($n-1$) distinct integers in the nearest and parallel diagonals to the main diagonal on either side. Thus, till now, I have filled $n+ 2(n-1)= (3n-2$) integers. We repeat this process of filling parallel and adjacent diagonals until each row and column( except the top and bottom row which have one less element than others) is filled with ($m-1$) distinct integers.

Now, I am stuck after this because I think it is more complicated than what I have learnt because I don't even know if this approach ensures that number of filled boxes get maximised or not.

**P.S.**: I have learnt till only basics of permutations and combinations so that might be the reason that I could not solve it. Although, I welcome all answers )

Thanks!

Comment: Where does this problem come from? I hope not from an open contest...

Comment: @coffee Hi. This was given by my teacher but only for given small values of $m$ and $n$ . However, I had generalised by assigning variables so that it can be more helpful instead of giving constant values like $n=4$ or $m=2$ etc. Thanks !

Comment: @An_Elephant Intuitively it feels like the answer should be $m^2$ because if I fill the top left submatrix with $m^2$ distinct value, then I'm stuck on using only those values for the rest. Do you have any example where the answer is greater than $m^2$ ?

Comment: @EnEm Yes. The original problem given by my teacher was $n=16$ and $m=4$ . However, the answer for this was $49$ which is greater than $4^2$. I cannot understood his solution as it was a little advanced for me. But I hope that here, I will learn new approaches and solutions from users. Thanks!

Comment: @An_Elephant Oh ok thanks, I'll explore this out and see how does that happen

Comment: For $n=16$ and $m=4$, the maximum is $64$, attained by four $4\times4$ blocks along the main diagonal.

Comment: Does each box have to contain a number, or can some be empty?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, we have to fill the boxes so that no box remains empty.

Comment: @RobPratt Yes, that would be the answer if we were not to fill full grid. But, we have to fill the grid fully. Thanks. I think I should add this in the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Has anyone found n=16 m=4 case with 49 distinct numbers?

Comment: @An_Elephant Can you put in your question some details about how n=16 m=4 can have 49 distinct numbers (and a number in each square)?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes but sorry. It's very late today here so I'll surely add this tomorrow. Also, as stated in question, the solution given by my teacher was very advanced for me because I was never a good math student. So, I hope for other solutions/approaches too :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139528/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-an-elephant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best case for when $n \ge 2m-1$ or $(n-(m-1)) | n$ has $n(m-1) + k$ distinct integers, where$k=\max\left\{d : d|n \land d\le \frac{n}{n-(m-1)}\right\}$ . The construction works for all $n>m$ cases, but I don't have the proof for all cases. Please edit/comment them out if you get them.

Here is the construction for the $k=1$ case :$$\left[\begin{matrix}\#_1 & \#_2 & \#_3 & \dots & \#_{m-2} & \#_{m-1} & \$ & \$ & \$ & \dots &\$& \$ \\ \$ & \#_1 & \#_2 & \#_3 & \dots & \#_{m-2} & \#_{m-1} &\$&\$&\dots &\$& \$ \\ \$ &\$& \#_1 & \#_2 & \#_3 & \dots & \#_{m-2} & \#_{m-1} &\$ &\dots &\$& \$ \\\ddots& \ddots& \ddots& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots& \ddots\\\$&\$&\$& \dots &\$&\$& \#_1 & \#_2 & \#_3 & \dots & \#_{m-2} & \#_{m-1}\\ \#_{m-1} &\$&\$& \dots &\$&\$&\$& \#_1 & \#_2 & \dots & \#_{m-3} & \#_{m-2}\\ \#_{m-2} & \#_{m-1} &\$& \dots &\$&\$&\$&\$& \#_1 & \dots & \#_{m-4} & \#_{m-3}\\\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots\\ \#_2 & \#_3 & \dots & \#_{m-2} & \#_{m-1} & \$ &\$&\$& \dots &\$&\$& \#_1 \end{matrix}\right]$$

Here all $\#$'s are distinct integers (no two $\#$ in the matrix are equal), and $\$$ is a single integer different from all $\#$'s (all $\$$ in the matrix are equal, but no $\#$ and $\$$ are equal). So total number of distinct integers = $n(m-1)+1$.

Formally, let the $t^{th}$ diagonal $d_t$ of the matrix be all the cells $\{a_{i,j} | j-i \equiv t-1 \pmod n \}$, then the union of diagonals $d_1, d_2, \dots d_{m-1}$ can be filled with all distinct integers (like $\{1,2,3,\dots n(m-1)\}$), and the union of diagonals $d_m, d_{m+1}, \dots d_n$ should be filled by a single integer (like $n(m-1)+1$).

For $k>1$ case the construction is mostly similar, but the $\$$ diagonals have to be intermixed with the $\#$ diagonals. Specifically $d_k, d_{2k}, d_{3k} \dots d_{(n-(m-1))k}$ diagonals will be $\$$ diagonals. There is no change in property of $\#$'s, they are still all distinct. But now $\$$'s can be $k$ distinct integers, $\$_1, \$_2, \dots \$_k$, and for any $\$_t$ it will be placed at all $\$$ diagonals, $a_{i,j}$ cells which have the property $\{a_{i,j} | i \equiv t+1 \pmod k \}$.

Here is a matrix with this construction for $n=6, m=4$ where $\$$ numbers are $19$ and $20$.

$$\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 19 & 7 & 19 & 13 & 19 \\ 20 & 2 & 20 & 8 & 20 & 14 \\ 15 & 19 & 3 & 19 & 9 & 19 \\ 20 & 16 & 20 & 4 & 20 & 10 \\ 11 & 19 & 17 & 19 & 5 & 19 \\ 20 & 12 & 20 & 18 & 20 & 6 \end{matrix}\right]$$

And another matrix with this construction for $n=6, m=5$ where $\$$ numbers are $25, 26$ and $27$.
$$\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 7 & 25 & 13 & 19 & 25 \\ 26 & 2 & 8 & 26 & 14 & 20 \\ 21 & 27 & 3 & 9 & 27 & 15 \\ 16 & 22 & 25 & 4 & 10 & 25 \\ 26 & 17 & 23 & 26 & 5 & 11 \\ 12 & 27 & 18 & 24 & 27 & 6 \end{matrix}\right]$$

---

The proof of this is by contradiction below. Also in the proof, I will be using some graph terminology, so I'll provide some short explanations for them here

- A graph $G$ is a collection of $N$ nodes (think of them as points), and $E$ edges where an edge is a connection between two nodes $(n_1, n_2)$ (think of them as lines between those points) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory#Definitions
- A path $p$ is some ordered list of distinct nodes $[n_1, n_2, \dots n_k] : k \ge 1$, where for each $i : 1\le i \le k-1$, nodes $n_i$ and $n_{i+1}$ have an edge between them : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)
- A $\textbf{connected}$ graph is a graph $G$ where for any two nodes $n_x$ and $n_y$ in $G$, they have a path between them, i.e., there are some nodes $n_1, n_2, \dots n_k : k \ge 0$ such that $[n_x, n_1, n_2, \dots n_k, n_y]$ is a valid path : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)

Proof :

Let the maximum number of distinct integers be $ M > n(m-1) + k$, where $k=\max\left\{d : d|n \land d\le \frac{n}{n-(m-1)}\right\}$. Also lets define a graph $G$ with $n$ indexed nodes (each corresponding to a row in our matrix), and with edges $\{(x,y) : \text{row}_x \text{ and } \text{row}_y \text{ have a common integer between them}\}$

Now I show that if this graph $G$ is connected, then the maximum number of distinct integers the matrix can have is $n(m-1)+1$ using induction :

- for $n=1$ : the graph contains a single row, which can have a maximum of $m-1+1 = m$ distinct integers.
- for $n + 1 \ge 2$ from $n$ :

  - for a connected graph with $ \ge 2$ nodes, we can always find a node $x$, such that, removing this node and all its' adjacent edges from the graph results in a connected graph (with $1$ less node).
  - The corresponding rows of this graph with $n$ nodes, will have a maximum of $n(m-1)+1$ distinct integers from Induction Hypothesis.
  - Now connecting the node $x$ and its' edges back to the graph, it will have at least one edge to some node $y$ in the reduced graph (because the original graph was connected).
  - This means row $x$ and row $y$ have at least one common integer between them, and hence row $x$ can add a maximum of $m-1$ distinct integers to the total $n(m-1)+1$.
  - Total number of distinct integers $\le n(m-1)+1 + (m-1) = (n+1)(m-1) + 1$, proving the induction.

So graph $G \textbf{ must be disconnected}$, or in other words, graph $G$ must have at least two disjoint connected components $G_1$ and $G_2$, where the number of nodes in both components $|G_1|, |G_2| > 0$. In our case, $\textbf{the number of connected components must be } > k$; because if there are only $t \le k$ connected components, $G_1, G_2, \dots G_t$, then any $G_i$ connected graph has $ \le |G_i|(m-1)+1$ number of distinct integers. Then the total number of distinct integers : $$\le \sum_{i=1}^t (|G_i|(m-1)+1) = (m-1)\sum_{i=1}^t|G_i| + \sum_{i=1}^t1 = n(m-1)+t < M$$

Now we have at least $k+1$ disjoint components , $G_1, G_2, \dots G_{k+1}$ :

- Lets take node $x_1$ from $G_1$, node $x_2$ from $G_2$ and so on until node $x_{k+1}$ from $G_{k+1}$. As any two of these nodes do not have an edge between them (they belong to different connected components), row $x_1$, row $x_2$ and so on until row $x_{k+1}$ will not have any common integer between them.
- From this we can say, that for each column $y$ of the matrix, it will have only a maximum of $m-(k+1)$ distinct integers, except the ${k+1}$ numbers which lie at the intersection of row $x_1$ and column $y$, row $x_2$ and column $y$ and so on.
- So the total number of distinct integers in the matrix $=$ extra distinct integers from each column $+$ maximum number of distinct integers in row $x_1$ $+$ maximum number of distinct integers in row $x_2 + \dots$  $$\begin{align}\le \sum_{y=1}^{n}(m-(k+1)) + \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}m &= n(m-(k+1)) + (k+1)m \\ &= n(m-1) - kn + km -k + k + m \\ &= n(m-1) -k(n-(m-1)) + m + k \end{align}$$

Now we can take three cases:

- Case 1 : $n \ge 2m-1$ : Here $k\le\frac{n}{n-(m-1)} < 2$, so $k = 1$. Also the maximum number of integers here are $\le n(m-1) -k(n-(m-1)) + m + k = n(m-1)-n+2m \le n(m-1) + 1$
- Case 2 : $(n-(m-1)) | n$ : Here $k = \frac{n}{n-(m-1)}$, so the maximum number of integers here are $\le n(m-1) -k(n-(m-1)) + m + k = n(m-1)-n+m+k \le n(m-1) + k$

Both of these cases violates $M > n(m-1) + k$. Hence the maximum number of distinct numbers is $n(m-1) + k$, where $k=\max\left\{d : d|n \land d\le \frac{n}{n-(m-1)}\right\}$.

Comment: How do you know that this construction yields the largest number of distinct numbers?

Comment: @RobPratt Sorry I forgot to include it in the post, will include it now

Comment: @RobPratt I had an error in my proof, see the note. I think we should be able to extend this proof to all cases, maybe by applying the same logic to columns as well, and then rows, and then columns, using some kinda induction. But its too late for me, I'll look at this tomorrow

Comment: Thanks for solution. But it is beyond the level of math I have learnt. Is there any simple solution which do not involve that big U and mod?

Comment: Anyway, thanks very much :)

Comment: @An_Elephant see  Daniel Mathias's comment on the other answer, that should explain to you how the answer is constructed. So you don't have to worry about the mod stuff. For the proof part though, it would be better if you google something you don't know to understand it for now.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution with $49$ distinct values, obtained via integer linear programming:

\begin{matrix}&1&11&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&27&12&1&1\\&1&25&1&1&1&1&1&1&8&1&10&1&1&1&1&1\\&44&42&1&1&
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&24&1&1&1\\&19&1&1&1&36&1&1&9&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\&1&1&6&1&1&1&5&1&17&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\&
1&1&46&1&1&28&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&47&1&1\\&1&1&13&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&41&26&1\\&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&22&1
&1&1&15&3\\&1&1&1&31&1&4&1&1&1&1&1&45&1&1&1&1\\&40&1&1&1&1&1&16&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&38\\&1&1&1&21&30&1
&1&14&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&33&1&1&1&1&32&2\\&1&1&1&1&35&1&1&1&1&37&1&43&1&1&1&1\\&1
&1&1&1&1&29&1&1&1&1&39&1&7&1&1&1\\&1&1&1&48&1&1&1&34&18&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\&1&1&1&1&1&1&20&1&1&49&1&23
&1&1&1&1\\\end{matrix}

Comment: Simplified solution (no programming required): [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2jnK.png) Shaded cells are distinct.

Comment: I haven't learn the linear programming yet but other users will find it helpful. Thanks very much for telling this new technique.

Comment: @DanielMathias But only 48 are filled there in the figure.

Comment: The unshaded cells in @DanielMathias’s figure correspond to the 49th integer.